# Aharonov-Bohm effect: a particle on a ring vs. a particle confined to the x-axis with periodic boundary conditions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gauge-theory, topology, gauge-invariance, gauge

Is there a fundamental difference between the Aharonov-Bohm effect in the two cases below?

(a) A particle on a ring (polar coordinates) with a magnetic flux through the ring.
(b) A particle confined to the x-axis with periodic boundary conditions when $\alpha\rightarrow 0$ for $H=(p_x-\alpha x) ^2/2m$.

Comment: Nope, there isn't.

Comment: a and b are exactly same in every manner.

Answer (score 1):

Classical and quantum mechanics allows you to freely choose a system of coordinates; therefore, as long as two coordinate systems describe the same topology, they are interchangeable. In this case, a circle is topologically equivalent to an interval with its ends identified, so there shouldn't be any difference.

Comment: I think there is a diffrence - Stokes theorem is ill defined because the interval can be the edge of many diffrent surfaces. In addition, you can use a vector potential that depends on x, for example $A_x=\alpha x$ and as a result your Hamiltonian will not be periodic but the wave-function would return to itself up to a translation gauge.

Comment: @Ard Shouldn't the interval and the circle both be the edge of the same set of surfaces?

Comment: Even if we assume they are, the Hamiltonian in case (b) is periodic only in the limit of $\alpha\rightarrow 0 $

Comment: I think that the first case describes a physical phenomenon while in the second the wave function returns to itself after an interval up to gauge. There is no magnetic field and the Stokes theorem does not hold.